# A packing algorithm ... kind of

Tags: algorithm, np-hard, computation

Given an array of items, each of which has a `value` and `cost`, **what's the best algorithm determine the items required to reach a minimum value at the minimum cost?** eg:

```
Item: Value -> Cost
-------------------
A     20   -> 11
B     7    -> 5
C     1    -> 2

MinValue = 30
naive solution: A + B + C + C + C. Value: 30, Cost 22
best option: A + B + B.            Value: 34, Cost 21
```

Note that the overall value:cost ratio at the end is irrelevant (`A + A` would give you the best value for money, but `A + B + B` is a cheaper option which hits the minimum value).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the knapsack problem. (That is, the decision version of this problem is the same as the decision version of the knapsack problem, although the optimization version of the knapsack problem is usually stated differently.) It is NP-hard (which means no algorithm is known that is polynomial in the "size" -- number of bits -- in the input). But if your numbers are small (the largest "value" in the input, say; the costs don't matter), then there is a simple dynamic programming solution.

Let best[v] be the minimum cost to get a value of (exactly) v. Then you can calculate the values best[] for all v, by (initializing all best[v] to infinity and):

```
best[0] = 0
best[v] = min_(items i){cost[i] + best[v-value[i]]}
```

Then look at best[v] for values upto the minimum you want plus the largest value; the smallest of those will give you the cost.

If you want the actual items (and not just the minimum cost), you can either maintain some extra data, or just look through the array of best[]s and infer from it.

Comment: Your dynamic programming solution is nice, but it seems to imply: 1) that each element can be taken more than one time; 2) that each value v can be reached exactly, which in general is not the case... Am I missing something?

Comment: That each element can be taken more than one time is implicit in the examples in the question :-) And although not all values can be reached exactly, if a value v can be reached exactly, then it can be reached using v-value[i] for some item i. [Otherwise, best[v] is ∞ by definition: empty min is ∞.]

Comment: "That each element can be taken more than one time is implicit in the examples in the question". You're right, sir! :D I feel like a Shakespeare monkey, as others on S.O. put it. Better go to sleep...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known as integer linear programming. It's NP-hard.
However, for small problems like your example, it's trivial to make a quick few lines of code to simply brute force all the low combinations of purchase choices.

NP-harddoesn't mean impossible or even expensive, it means your problem becomes rapidly slower to solve with larger scale problems. In your case with just three items, you can solve this in mere microseconds.

For the exact question of what's the best algorithm in general.. there are entire textbooks on it. A good start is [good old Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)

Comment: Using general Integer Linear Programming methods for this one is overkill, IMHO, especially when (1) in the easy case, there are very simple brute-force or dynamic programming solutions, as you observed (2) in the hard case, there are specialised algorithms of knapsack which will outperform general ILP. (Also, you've linked to the article on Linear Programming -- LP in general doesn't give integer solutions.)

Answer (score -1):

**Edit This answer is redacted on account of being factually incorrect. Following the advice in this will only cause you harm.**

This is not actually the knapsack problem, because it assumes that you cannot pack more items than there is space for in some container. In you case you want to find the cheapest combination that will fill up the space, allowing for the fact that overflow may occur.

My solution, which I don't know is the optimal but it should be pretty close, would be to compute for each item the cost benefit ratio, find the item with the highest cost benefit and fill the structure with this item until there isn't space for one more item. Then I would test to see if there was a combination with any of the other available items that could fill the available slot for less that the cost of one of the cheapest items and then if such a solution exist, use that combination otherwise use one more of the cheapest items.

*Amenddum* This may actually also be NP-complete, but I am not sure yet. Anyway for all practical purposes this variation should be much faster than the naive solution.

Comment: This problem is trivially equivalent to the knapsack (decision) problem -- "can a value of at least 30 be achieved without exceeding the cost 21?" And solving this problem solves knapsack as well, which is why this problem is NP-complete (we have a polynomial-time many-one reduction from Knapsack to this one). I said all this in my answer. :P      Your greedy solution doesn't always give the right answer: the same counterexamples as for knapsack also kill this one.